# single "*" wildcard in Lift SiteMap Menu entry

Tags: scala, lift

It looks as though the Lift SiteMap DSL supports both "*" and "**" as wildcards. Apparently "**" is used only at the end of a path, when you want to match all paths that start with some prefix. But I don't understand how "*" is meant to be used. I had hoped it would act as a wildcard for one path component in a path. So something like:

```
    Menu("Category Home Pages") / "category" / * / "home"
```

would match:

```
    /category/alpha/home
    /category/beta/home
    /category/gamma/home
    etc.
```

But this doesn't work for me. (I get a 404 even though the path exists in the filesystem.) If this is not supposed to be the function of "*", could someone please enlighten me? I've only been able to find documentation for "**".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`*` will matched a single level path, and `**` will match any level of path.

For example, as you say,

```
Menu("Category Home Pages") / "category" / * / "home"
```

will match

```
/category/alpha/home
/category/beta/home
/category/gamma/home
etc.
```

But you still need HTML template called `home.html` in `webapp/category/alpha/` or other matching templates.

If you don't have corresponding HTML templates, Lift will response a 404 error.

Comment: Thanks. Today it works. Pilot error I suppose, or maybe I just needed to believe.